# how to use between in if statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a date condition here

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(a=1 OR b=0 OR c=1 OR d=0 AND date BETWEEN '1336544083' AND '1336544081'  1, 0)),0) AS AC FROM tbl_people WHERE `Id` = '2'
```

is this method correct?.

Comment: It seems to be, does it work?

Comment: nope it's not working...

Comment: What is the error reported by mysql?

Comment: Aren't you missing a comma after the 2nd date?

Comment: `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Do you really intend the date condition to only apply when `d=0`? I'd usually add explicit parentheses rather than mixing `AND`s and `OR`s in a complex condition.

Comment: i want to get the deatils of colum AC after executing the values in or and then i have to get the count of column 'AC' between those date condition

Comment: @coolboy: then you need parentheses